# Gradle Disable Ant Logs

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am triggering the jasper report compilation from my gradle build plugin

```
target.ant {
                    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.WARN
                    taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: "net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask", classpath:target.configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
                    jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
                    jrc(srcdir: "${target.projectDir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/report-designs", destdir: jasperTargetDir) {
                        classpath(path: target.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
                        include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
                    }
                }
```

This task creates lot of verbose log out put which I need to disable.

I tried adding the below line - but it was not helpful

*logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.WARN*

While creating the taskdef for ant , is it possible to control the log level ?